# send email only if field has multiple messages cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.0 and I a have a shell that sends me a daily email for each account that has a message. I now want it to only send me an email for that account if it has 5 messages or more. How do I do this? My current code (which isn't working) is this:

```
$items = $this->ReportLog->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                 'account' => 'msg' > 5
            )));

foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $message = 'Account Name: '. $item['ReportLog']['account'] . "\n" . 'Message: '. $item['ReportLog']['msg'];

$this->ReportLog->sendMail($message, 'me@myEmail.com');
    }
```

This shell works just fine without the conditions so I know there is something wrong with that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Currently how would you find out how many messages an account has?

Comment: Are the messages stored in the `ReportLog` table or a separate table? Could you please add some demo data of the table content to your question so we understand the data structure, fields and relations?